# How many bit strings of length n are palindromes?

Tags: combinatorics, palindrome

While reading in a Discrete maths text book, there was this question:

> How many bit strings of length n are palindromes?

The answer is:

> $2^\frac{n+1}{2}$ for odd and $2^\frac{n}{2}$ for even.

I searched it on the internet and people were saying that first $\frac{n}{2}$ ($\frac{n+1}{2}$ for odd ) can be selected arbitrarily and the next bits has to be determined.

I got the first part but I fail to understand the second. How can a palindrome can be determined by the first part?

Please explain it using an example. Thanks!

Comment: It is really trivial, I suggest you try to list all palindromes of length $2, 3, 4$ and $5$, then you will surely know it.

Comment: I did it. I just fail to understand it's formula. For palindrome the first part would be similar to second part. So, it should be 2^n/2 * 2^n/2 . Right?

Comment: " How can a palindrome can be determined by the first part?"  Um, seriously?  Do you know what a palindrome is?  The second part of the palindrome is always exactly the first part backwards.

Comment: Okay.  If the first part of an even length palindrome is "abcdefghi" the second part *has* to be "ihgfedcba" so the palindrome is "abcdefghiihgfedcba".  For every possible "abcdefghi" there is *exactly* one palindrome of the form "abcdefghiihgfedcba"  As there are $2^{m/2}$ ways to do "abcdefghi" there are $2^{m/2}$ ways to do "abcdefghiihgfedcba".

Comment: "For palindrome the first part would be similar to second part."  Not just similar.  *Exactly* the same but backwards.  "So, it should be $2^n/2 * 2^n/2$ . Right? "  Uh, no.  There's $2^n/2$ ways for the first part;.  *One* way for the second part.  so $2^n/2*1$ ways total.

Comment: Palindromes of length 2.  There are 2 ways to do  0x, and  1x, so there are 2 ways to do 00, and 11.  Palindromes of length 3:  There are four ways to do 00x, 01x,10x,11x so there are four ways to do 000,010,101,111.  Palindrome of length 4:  There are four ways to do 00xx,01xx, 10xx,11xx so there are four ways to do 0000,0110,1001,1111.  Palindromes of length 5: There are eight ways to do abcxx sot there or eight ways to do abc(ba).  Etc.

Comment: Equivalent to [Number of n-digit palindromes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287582/318073), but we simply have base $10$ instead of $2$.

Comment: Wow fleablood you were being very condescending here.  “Um, seriously? Do you not know what a palindrome is?”.  Learn some manners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a string is length $n$, then we can write it as either being length $2k+1$ if $n$ is odd, or $2*k$ if $n$ is even, where $k \in \mathbb Z$.

In either case, the first half of the digits determine the values of the second half of the digits. Indeed, let $$(a_m)_{m=1}^{n}$$ be a string that is a palindrome. Then $a_1 = a_n, a_2 = a_{n-1},\ldots$ If $n$ is odd, then $a_{k+1} = a_{k+1}$ otherwise $a_k = a_{k+1}$.

Thus, there are $2$ choices for the value of $a_1$, $2$ choices for $a_2$, $\ldots$, and $2$ choices for $a_k$. If $n$ is odd, then there are also two choices for the middle digits $a_{k+1}$. Combining, we see that if $n$ is odd, we have a total of $2^{k+1}$ possible choices; if $n$ is even then we have a total of $2^k$ possible choices. Substituting back for $n$ gives $2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ choices for $n$ odd and $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ for $n$ even.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P_{n}$ be the number of palindromes of length n. Then the recursive formula for $P_{n}$ can be given as,
           $P_{n} = 2.P_{n-2}$, with base case $P_{1} =1$ and $P_{2} = 2$,
that can be conversed easily into $P_{n} = 2^{n/2}$, if n is even or $P_{n} = 2^{(n+1)/2}$, if n is odd.

Comment: The Question, not quite a year old at this point, does ask that the explanation be accompanied by "an example".  Since an Accepted Answer exists, I suppose there is some flexibility in providing the solution by a different route.