# How many symmetrical strings of length $m$ can be formed using $n$ symbols?

Tags: combinatorics, palindrome

I'm having trouble trying to tackle this problem and need some help explaining the approach.

My task is this:

Given an alphabet with $n$ symbols, how many palindromes of length $m$ can be formed?

For instance if the alphabet is $\{a,b\}$ and $m=1,2,3$, you can make: $a,b, aa,bb, aaa,bbb,aba$ and $bab$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try some more examples with small n and m, like you did, and see how many you get (for a specific m ... don't add them up yet) so for n=2 and m=1, you get 2, for n=2 and m=2 you get 2 as well, but for n=2 and m=3 you get 4 ... try some more values (n=3, m=4 ...)  you may start to see a pattern. Then, when you have that pattern as a hypothesis, try and prove it.

Comment: Or: don't think about it and just copy the answer from Jorge.

Comment: Also see: [Number of n-digit palindromes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287582/318073), and [How many bit strings of length n are palindromes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1264613/318073).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $m=2k$ you just have to select the first $k$ elements freely, and this determines the other $k$. So there are $n^k$ palindromes.

If $m=2k+1$ you can select the first $k+1$ elements freely and this determines the other $k$. So there are $n^{k+1}$ palindromes.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k(m)$ denote the number of palindromes of length $m$ that can be formed.

It's clear that $k(1) = n$, since every letter is a palindrome by itself. We also have $k(2) = n$, since only two copies of the same letter can form a palindrome of length $2$.

Then, for a palindrome of length $j$ > 2, what happens if you take off the first and last letter? You again have a palindrome. How many options are there for the first and last letter? How many options are there for the middle?