# Number of 4 digit palindromes

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, palindrome

Can you prove that there are exactly $90$ elements in the set of numbers having $4$ digits which are palindromes?

This is not a tricky question. I am just trying to understand the concept of proofs better.

Comment: See [Number of n-digit palindromes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287582/318073).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: a four-digit palindrome must look like $ABBA$ where $A$ and $B$ are digits, and $A$ is nonzero. The number of ways can you choose $A$ and $B$ is the number of four-digit palindromes.

Comment: I understand what you wrote. And thank you for that. I wonder how a structured proof will look